display PDF with CGPDFDocument，but it dispaly incomplete
I use CGPDFDocument to  display PDF with swift，but some elements are not displayed。
when use PDFView，it show normally
what should I do？
CGPDFDocument：

PDFView：

    func drawInContext(context:CGContext){
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        let pageRef:CGPDFPage = self.document!.page(at: self.pageNum)!;
        let pageRect: CGRect = self.document!.page(at:self.pageNum)!.getBoxRect(CGPDFBox.mediaBox)
        let scale: CGFloat = min(self.bounds.size.width / pageRect.size.width , self.bounds.size.height / pageRect.size.height)
            context.setFillColor(red: 1.0,green: 1.0,blue: 1.0,alpha: 1.0)
            context.fill(self.bounds)
            context.saveGState()
            context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: self.bounds.size.height)
            context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            context.scaleBy(x: scale, y: scale)
            context.drawPDFPage(pageRef)
            context.restoreGState()
    }

I tried to use PDFView,it show normally
